# Trying to get the content from one Express route as the content of pdf report in jsreports

Tags: node.js, express, jsreport

I have this route working if I pass it a public url within the phantom object but I want to pass in the content rendered from another route.  Is this possible?

```
  app.route('/pdfreport')
        .get(function (req, res) {
            var request = require('request');
            request('/about/employers', function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

                    var client = require("jsreport-client")('jsreportsever', 'usernamem', 'password')

                    client.render({
                        template: {
                            content: body,
                            phantom: {
                                orientation: "portrait",
                                width: "300px"
                            }
                        }
                    },function(err, response) {
                        if (err) {
                            return next(err);
                        }
                        response.pipe(res);
                    });
                }
            })

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but why don't you call the code from that other route directly? Server requesting itself over http seems like a slowdown for nothing.

Anyway your code should also work. You are just missing full url in the request. It should be something like:

```
request(req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + '/about/employers', ...
```

Comment: I guess my question is how do I get the rendered version of the page without rendering before the pdf... I want to grab the html that would normally render and not display it but process the pdf... if I can do it without a two step process that would be great

Comment: Maybe you can use app.render to get the html you put afterwards into jsreport. http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.render